# How to implement mock location?

Tags: android

I need to use fake GPS coordinates for my device without GPS. I am trying to use this manual: http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html

But import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient is not available. As I know it is deprecated. But how to implement mock location now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#setMockLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.location.Location))

Answer (score 1):

Further to Michael's answer.

1. Init GoogleApiClient:

   ```
   private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
   ```
2. Connect the client:

   ```
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   ```
3. Set new location:

   ```
   Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   location.setLatitude(48.446743);
   location.setLongitude(52.44672);
   location.setAccuracy(4.0f);
   location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
   location.setTime(currentTime);
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mGoogleApiClient, location);
   ```
4. When we are finished, it's needed to disconnect client:

   ```
   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
       mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
   }
   ```

Comment: hey, I have tried this code and it works. But only until the app is open. As soon as I close the app and open "Google Maps", my "real" location becomes my current location. Any ideas on how to fix that?